# Solid state RF switch with feedback: does it exist?

Tags: rf, switches, solid-state-devices

I am looking for a solid state RF switch (for example, PIN diode, but not only) that features a feedback of the switch status.

For electromechanical RF switches this seems relatively easy to found, because the feedback is just a contact that closes/opens when the RF contact is actuated.
On the contrary, looks like that such a feedback is hard to find for solid state switches.

The switch can be SPST or SP2T.

I've already searched through the main websites (minicircuits, digikey, ...), but I feel I'm out of luck.

Does this feature exist?

Comment: The activate signal is the feedback signal.

Comment: You could also measure power in and out, but this only verifies operation when signal is present. I'm not sure there's any failure mechanism where an analog switch for example wouldn't fail outright (e.g. supply shorted) and also DC conduction wouldn't work (assuming it's not an internally AC coupled type or anything).

Comment: Is there a reason there must be feedback?

Comment: @Andyaka I also thought so, but I wonder if there is something alike the feedback in an electromechanical relay. theoretically (?) you can apply the control/activation signal and the switch fails

Comment: @TimWilliams that is something that I plan to do nevertheless, because I need to verify different point of failure in the overall system

Comment: @Drew maybe not for the device itself. indeed, this is a requirement for the system which the rf switch is a part of

Comment: Well, to reiterate what Andy said, what would the problem be with splitting the signal that controls the switch and sending that out as the "feedback"?